# Can I use Pokemon Home to sort my boxes permanently

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield, pokemon-lets-go, pokemon-home

Can I use [Pokemon Home](https://home.pokemon.com/de-de/) to permamently sort my boxes in Sw/Sh, Let's Go Pickachu / Eevee?
I saw an option to get a sort of all joined boxes, but it is not persistent.

Answer (score 3):

While you can use the Switch Pokemon Home app to manage your in game boxes, the process is still manual and no different than using the in game management systems (other than having access to Home boxes to be slightly more convenient maybe).

Using the Sort/Filter options are only temporary as a way to locate Pokemon between Home and the connected game (it sorts all Pokemon in Home Boxes and the Switch game into one list).